# Printing a formatted string from a list up to a specified character

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to print out a formatted string based on a string that is contained within a list. However, I want to print out the formatted string to stop at a comma.

Example: `a = ['Apple pie, A couple of oranges, Eggs benedict, Chocolate Milkshake']`

I want my formatted string to look like this:

```
Shopping list: 
Fruits: Apple pie, A couple of oranges
Poultry: Eggs benedict
Drinks: Chocolate Milkshake
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: How are we supposed to infer from your list that Fruits should have 2 strings following it.  You need some way of defining when to go to the next key.  That being said, `split(',')` is your friend.

Comment: Do you have any attempt at all to show us?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do 

`statement = ('Fruits: {0} {1}\nPoultry: {2}\nDrinks: {3})

print statement` 

but that doesn't work.

Comment: If the list is actually as small as this one you could go about accomplishing it using indexes and/or the split() method.

Comment: @Ken Are you sure the strings are always in that order? Two fruits, one poulty and one drink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a dictionary storing the name and possible food items that each food type is a part of:

```
testing = {'Fruits':['apple', 'oranges'], 'Poultry':['eggs'], 'Drinks':['Chocolate']}
a = ['Apple pie, A couple of oranges, Eggs benedict, Chocolate Milkshake']
a = a[0].split(', ')
final_data = "Shopping list:\n{}".format('\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(h, ', '.join(i for i in a if any(c.lower() in i.lower() for c in b))) for h, b in testing.items()))
```

Output:

```
Shopping list:
Fruits: Apple pie, A couple of oranges
Poultry: Eggs benedict
Drinks: Chocolate Milkshake
```

You can expand the testing data by adding additional food types (keys) and associated terms (list of values).

Answer (score 2):

As it is, you're not storing enough information to create the output you're looking for.  I would recommend storing your information in a dictionary like so:

```
foods = {
    'Fruits': ['Apple pie', 'A couple of oranges'],
    'Poultry': ['Eggs benedict'],
    'Drinks': ['Chocolate Milkshake']
}
```

Then, you have all the information you need to create the desired output like so:

```
output = 'Shopping list:\n'

for category in foods:

    category_str = ''
    for food in foods[category]:
        category_str += '{}, '.format(food)
    category_str = category_str[:-2] # cut off trailing comma and space

    output += '{}: {}\n'.format(category, category_str)

output = output[:-1] # cut off trailing newline

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_foods = (('fruits',('Apple pie', 'A couple of oranges')), ('poultry', ('Eggs benedict')), ('drinks', ('Chocolate Milkshake')))

print "Shopping list: \n"
for category, food_list in list_of_foods:
    print "".join('{}: {} \n'.format(category, ','.join(food_list))
```